# Python: How to use if any("str" in item for item in list)?

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, any

The code snippet below returns an error that global name 'item' is not defined. How do I use if any(...) correctly to search for and print a string if found in a list?

```
def walk:
    list = ["abc", "some-dir", "another-dir", ".git", "some-other-dir"]
    if any (".git" in item for item in list):
        print item,
```

Comment: You don't. Don't use `any()` if you want to enumerate all the matching items.

Comment: Also, `item` will only exist within scope of your `any` method call. This is also why you are getting that error message for `item` not being defined.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Do you mean to suggest that I use 'all' instead? What if I just wanted to find any one instance? Would the use of 'any' be a valid use case in that instance?

Comment: @idjaw yes that makes sense to me, so how would I fix it though? By defining item as a global?

Comment: @SiddharthPatil Look at the answer that was provided. All the information is there for you and very well explained.

Comment: @SiddharthPatil: no, `any()` always returns true, or false, nothing else. Use `next()` on a generator instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't. Don't use `any()` if you want to enumerate all the matching items. The name `item` only exists in the scope of the generator expression passed to `any()`, all you get back from the function is `True` or `False`. The items that matched are no longer available.

Just loop directly over the list and test each in an `if` test:

```
for item in lst:
    if ".git" in item:
        print item,
```

or use a list comprehension, passing it to `str.join()` (this is [faster than a generator expression in this specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061024/100297)):

```
print ' '.join([item for item in list if ".git" in item])
```

or, using Python 3 syntax:

```
from __future__ import print_function

print(*(item for item in list if ".git" in item))
```

If you wanted to find just the *first* such a match, you can use `next()`:

```
first_match = next(item for item in list if ".git" in item)
```

Note that this raises `StopIteration` if there are no such matches, unless you give `next()` a default value instead:

```
first_match = next((item for item in list if ".git" in item), None)
if first_match is not None:
    print first_match,
```

Comment: @MartijnPeters, Thank you!